# Graphing this with Jquery.Flot or similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, graphing

I'm trying to draw this chart with Flot. There's a flat line from 0 to 10 (at y=1). and points at x=2, x=3, x=7 all also at y=1.

```
________O____O_______________O_____________

0   1   2    3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

I'm also open to anything else other than Flot, if there's a clear example how to do what I'm trying to do, that I can almost copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy using flot:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var someLine = [[0, 1], [10, 1]];
    var somePoints = [[2,1],[3,1],[7,1]];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"),[
    {
        data: someLine,
        lines: { show: true}
    },
    {
        data: somePoints,
        points: { show: true}
    }
    ]);
});
</script>
```

[image]